# Action of $\mathbb{R}^N$ over linear operators $\mathcal{L}(X,\mathbb{R}^N) $

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ a normed vector space and $\bar{B}(\boldsymbol{0},1):=\{x \in X:\|x\|\leq 1\}$. Given $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $A \in \mathcal{L}(X,\mathbb{R}^N)$ a linear operator and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Define a functional $\beta \cdot A : X \to \mathbb{R} $ by $(\beta \cdot A) (x):=\langle \beta, A(x) \rangle_{N}$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_N $ is the usual dot product over $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^N$, then $\alpha \in \overline{A(\bar{B}(0,1))}$ if only if $|\langle\beta,\alpha\rangle_N| \leq \|\beta \cdot A \|_{X'} \quad \forall \beta \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

**My attemps:** Suppose $\alpha \in \overline{A(\bar{B}(0,1))}$, then we can take a sequence $(\alpha_n)_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N,$ where, $\alpha_n:=A(x_n)$ with $\|x_n\|\leq 1 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\|\alpha-\alpha_n\|_{\mathbb{R}^N} \to 0 $. Then
\begin{align} 
    |\langle\beta, \alpha_n\rangle_N|=|\langle\beta, A(x_n)\rangle_N|\leq \|\beta \cdot A\|_{X'} \quad \forall \beta \in \mathbb{R}^N,
\end{align}
Taking $n \to \infty$, we get the first inequality
\begin{align}
|\langle\beta,\alpha\rangle_N| \leq \|\beta \cdot A \|_{X'} \quad \forall \beta \in \mathbb{R}^N. \tag{*}
\end{align}
For the converse, suppose (*), then for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a $\|x_n\|\leq 1$ with
\begin{align}
 \|\beta \cdot A \|_{X'}-\frac{1}{n} &< |\langle\beta, A(x_n)\rangle_N| \quad \forall 
\beta \in \mathbb{R}^N, \\
|\langle\beta,\alpha\rangle_N|-\frac{1}{n} &<
\end{align}
On this step I would like to remove absolute values, but I'm not quite sure if that is possible but if I could, I would get
\begin{align}
\langle \beta, \alpha-A(x_n)  \rangle < \frac{1}{n} \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}
\end{align}
Choosing $\beta := \alpha-A(x_n)$ and making $n \to \infty$ I would get the result.

However the book suggest me proceed by contradiction that means, suppose there is $\delta>0$ such that $\|A(x)-\alpha\|_{\mathbb{R}^N}>\delta \quad \forall \|x\|\leq 1 $, but I didn't get any useful there.